# Defining two foreign keys in one entity targeting one other entity in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have the entities set up as follows

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship, Mapped, DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class UserEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    last_message = relationship("MessageEntity", back_populates="from_user", uselist=False)

class MessageEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "message"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    from_user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    to_user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    # relationships
    from_user = relationship("UserEntity", back_populates="last_message", foreign_keys=[from_user_id], uselist=False)
```

This describes that some users can have their last message, that is in a one-to-one relationship with the `from_user` column in the `MessageEntity`. Now I want to store `to_user_id` inside `MessageEntity` without any relationship with `UserEntity`, it should just store a User's ID, but now when I add this field I get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship UserEntity.last_message - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I'm not sure which relationship SQLAlchemy is trying to infer by having a `to_user_id` foreign key, but I only want it to store a simple id, with no strings attached. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to specify the `foreign_keys` on both sides of the relationship.

The first definition uses a string because the class is not defined yet, `foreign_keys="[MessageEntity.from_user_id]"`, which is mentioned at the bottom of [handling-multiple-join-paths](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths).

- Also note that you can either include the list symbols **inside** the string:
  `foreign_keys="[MessageEntity.from_user_id]"`
- Or exclude the list symbols:
  `foreign_keys="MessageEntity.from_user_id"`
- BUT you cannot leave it outside if you are using strings, ie. DOES NOT WORK: `foreign_keys=["MessageEntity.from_user_id"]`

```py
class UserEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    last_message = relationship("MessageEntity", back_populates="from_user", uselist=False, foreign_keys="[MessageEntity.from_user_id]")

class MessageEntity(Base):
    __tablename__ = "message"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    content: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    from_user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    to_user_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    # relationships
    from_user = relationship("UserEntity", back_populates="last_message", foreign_keys=[from_user_id], uselist=False)
```

Comment: Since you use `Mapped` for all other fields, you can also define relationship fields as follows: `last_message: Mapped["MessageEntity"] = relationship(back_populates="from_user", foreign_keys="[MessageEntity.from_user_id]")` and `from_user: Mapped[UserEntity] = relationship(back_populates="last_message", foreign_keys=[from_user_id])`.

Comment: Thanks :) it looks a bit redundant as this could be inferred from `back_populates="from_user"` and `from_user` having `foreign_key=[from_user_id]`. Though it also works if removing `back_populates` from `last_message`.

Comment: If you omit `back_populates`, SQLAlchemy will not update related object before commit. You can learn more here (SQLModel based on SQLAlchemy, so in SQLAlchemy it works the same): https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/relationship-attributes/back-populates/